# How to find the nth letter of the phrase, and keep all the starting letters?

Tags: java

how do I Input an integer (n), then output the first n characters of the phrase using only the for loop?

for example, the input is 1 (option number), Hussain Omer (String name), 9 (index)
the output should be Hussain O (see how the first letters are kept and the nth letter is given afterward)

this is my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Phrases{
    public static void main (String[]args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (option == 1){
                int x = keyboard.nextInt();
                    for (int y = 0; y < phrase.length(); y++){
                        char n = phrase.charAt(y);
                            if (y < phrase.length()-y) 
                                System.out.print(n);
                            if (y == x - 1) 
                                System.out.print(n);
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to print the character at index, `y` where `y < x`. Note that you also need to check `y < phrase.length()` to avoid `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `x >= phrase.length()`.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (option == 1) {
            int x = keyboard.nextInt();
            for (int y = 0; y < x && y < phrase.length(); y++) {
                System.out.print(phrase.charAt(y));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
1
Hussain Omer
9
Hussain O
```

Alternatively, you can use [substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) for it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (option == 1) {
            int x = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (x < phrase.length())
                System.out.println(phrase.substring(0, x));
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
1
Hussain Omer
9
Hussain O
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212219/discussion-on-answer-by-arvind-kumar-avinash-how-to-find-the-nth-letter-of-the-p).

Comment: Hello Arvind, I have a question I posted called "How do I print the letter of a phrase involving indesOf() method?" Could you please reply to that? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61397336/how-to-print-a-letter-involving-the-indexof-method-note-a-letter-should-be-p

Answer (score 0):

Just change your for-cycle. If you want to output only limited number of characters, then just limit for-cycle to have that many steps and output the characters.

```
                for (int y = 0; y < x; y++){
                    char n = phrase.charAt(y);
                    System.out.print(n);
                }
```

Comment: The condition should be `y < x && y < phrase.length()` to avoid `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `x >= phrase.length()`.

Comment: I understand the y < phrase.length() but what does the y < x mean?