# How to print a letter involving the indexOf() Method? Note: A letter should be printed instead of the index position

Tags: java

I want to print a letter based on the index position. Although, there is more added to that but here's the requirement, I know it involves the charAt(); method but how would I use the method to find the string of this following requirement: Inputs a second string from the user.  Outputs the character after the first instance of the string in the phrase.  If the string is not in the phrase, outputs a statement to that effect. For example if the input s "upside down" and "d", then it should output "e" so it should be the character after the input character. Other example, the input is Upside down, and do. The output should be "w"

```
else if (option == 3){
                int first = 0;
                String letter = keyboard.next();
                first = phrase.indexOf(letter);
                char n = phrase.charAt(first + 1);
            if (first == -1){
                    System.out.print("'"+letter+"' is not in '"+phrase+"'");
            }
            else {
                    System.out.print(n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems you have asked the same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter option: ");
        int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        if (option == 3) {
            System.out.print("Enter phrase: ");
            String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter a substring to search after: ");
            String substring = keyboard.next();
            int index;
            if (phrase.length() > substring.length()) {
                index = phrase.indexOf(substring);
                if (index != -1 && index < phrase.length() - substring.length()) {
                    System.out.println(phrase.charAt(index + substring.length()));
                }
                if (index == phrase.length() - substring.length()) {
                    System.out.println("'" + substring + "' is the last substring in '" + phrase + "'");
                }
                if (index == -1) {
                    System.out.print("'" + substring + "' is not in '" + phrase + "'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter option: 3
Enter phrase: upside down
Enter a substring to search after: do
w
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter option: 3
Enter phrase: upside down
Enter a substring to search after: down
'down' is the last substring in 'upside down'
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter option: 3
Enter phrase: upside down
Enter a substring to search after: x
'x' is not in 'upside down'
```

Comment: When i enter "Upside down" and "do" it should output "w" but it outputs "e"

Comment: `do` is not a letter. If you want to search for a letter or word, the program needs to be changed. Do you want me to help you do it?

Comment: Yes can u help me with it?

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Oops I am sorry but I cant use substring, it has to be with for loop or anything else that is not a built-in method of java. Sorry again

Comment: I haven't used the `substring` function. It's just that I've named the variable as `substring`. You can rename the variable to anything.

Comment: Oh okay Thank You, this will also work for letters too right?

Comment: Yes, of course! A letter is also a substring of length `1`.